# python class type error using inheritance

Tags: python

I'm getting this error when I run this code.
I've already passed 4 arguments, so I do not understand what is happening

This is the error

```
TypeError:super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

This is the code

```
class Employee:

    raise_amt = 1.04

    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.email = first + '.' + last + '@email.com'
        self.pay = pay

    def fullname(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first, self.last)

    def apply_raise(self):
        self.pay = int(self.pay * self.raise_amt)


class Developer(Employee):
    raise_amt = 1.10

    def __init__(self, first, last, pay, prog_lang):
        super().__init__(first, last, pay)
        self.prog_lang = prog_lang


dev_1 = Developer('Corey', 'Schafer', 50000,'python')
print(dev_1.email)
print(dev_1.prog_lang)
```

Comment: For Python 3.6.8 this code works fine!

Comment: Don't you use Python 2?

Comment: I ran this code in the terminal with python 3 and it worked fine ,but my atom editor is using python 2. how can I make atom use python 3 instead of python2?